# Reusing the eclipse plug in to create the customized plug in

Tags: eclipse-plugin

**Problem:**   I am using the eclipse editor plugin to create the customized plug in.  So in that plug in i will be using only some classes to get the customized view of the editor.  But I will not be using all classes now for example there are classes Class A,Class B, and Class C in the editor plug in and Class A will be initiating Class C.Now in my customized plugin I will be extending the Class C and customize the Class as per my requirement and I don't want to modify the Class A.

Actual problem is if open the eclipse editor i want Class A to initiate the extended Class C present in my plug in and not present in the eclipse editor plug in.

I.e During compile time binding i want Class A of the eclipse plug in to bind with the extended Class C present in my plugin.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should be having an activator class in your plugin, you need to override start method to instantiate class C.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the behavior of an existing editor by trying to extend its classes in a new plugin.

If the existing editor provides 'extension points' to add new functionality to can extend it using those.

You can write a new editor using the classes from an existing plugin provided the existing plugin exports the packages you need to use.

You can sometimes use the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to suppress existing menus items, but this will require research to identify menu ids.

You can also sometimes add to menus by using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point. Again this requires research to identify menu ids. The 'plug-in Spy' may help with this.

Comment: Actually eclipse has given some menu option in the editor but i don't want there options to be viewed instead i want custom new options in the menu .But eclipse are creating the menu using the class in the editor plug in so is there any solution for this they don't provide any extension point to change this class

Comment: Added some info on activities and adding to menus.